# Data Not Being Inserted Into Sqlite3 Database Using Python 2.7

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7

I'm having trouble inserting data into my table. I have a list of stocks that I pass to the function getStockData.

I use a for loop to iterate through the list and get the data for each ticker symbol. At the end I put all the information into a dictionary. My final step is to insert the data into a table. I've been unsuccessful at inserting the data in the dictionary into my table.

```
def getStockData(x):

   nowdate = raw_input("What Is Todays Date?: ")
   print "Todays list has %d stocks on it\n" % len(x)

   for stock in x:

        stockPrice = ystockquote.get_price(stock)

        stockPriceChange = ystockquote.get_change(stock)

        originalPrice = float(stockPrice) + (float(stockPriceChange) * -1)

        changePercentage = (float(stockPriceChange) / originalPrice) * 100

        stockDict = {'Date': nowdate, 'Ticker Symbol': stock, 'Closing Price': stockPrice, 
                 'Price Change': stockPriceChange, 'Percentage Changed': changePercentage} 

        conn = db.connect('stocks.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('insert into losers values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (stockDict['Date'], stockDict['Ticker Symbol'], stockDict['Price Change'],
                                 stockDict['Percentage Changed'], stockDict['Closing Price']) )

        conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forget to commit your data to your DB before close.

Try

```
conn.commit()
```